# What is the first harem anime or manga?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

Harem anime and manga has become pretty popular since the 90s. The first harem anime I saw was Tenchi, but I think that studio might've had an earlier, similar show. I think the definition of a harem anime or manga might be a bit subjective, so I will try to be specific here.

To me, a harem anime or manga is one where multiple female characters surround a male lead.

At least two must be attracted to him.

The female characters who are attracted to the lead must appear regularly.

What is the first anime or manga that fits this description?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in putting your thought on https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43860/minimum-amount-of-people-for-harem